# How to use symprod with symbolic arrays?

Tags: octave, symbolic-math

I would like to have this equation solved symbolically:

> x_i = x_0 + \prod_{j = 0}^{i-1}(a_{3-j})

I wrote the following script, which works until I call `symprod`:

```
try
  pkg load symbolic
end
a = sym('a', [1 3]);
syms x0 i
x0*symprod(a(i), i, [1 3])
```

The error message says:

> error: subscript indices must be integers or boolean

However, this works:

```
a(2)
```

> ans = (sym) a12

What is wrong with my code?
(I also tried with Matlab Symbolic Toolbox; does not work either, but error message is different.)

Comment: Isn't your expected result this: `x0+prod(a)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is already with the expression `a(i)`, such indexing is not possible:

```
>> a(i)
error: subscript indices must be integers or boolean
```

In a situation where a are the integer indices, you are probably better off using `prod`:

```
>> prod(a)
ans = (sym) a₁₁⋅a₁₂⋅a₁₃
```

An alternative is to work with functions:

```
>> syms fa(i)
>> e=x0*symprod(fa(i), i, [1 3])
e = (sym) x₀⋅fa(1)⋅fa(2)⋅fa(3)
```

Comment: Indeed, the function did the trick. I now have the complete solution.
But what I don't understand is, when I evaluate it, why not all `symprod` are expanded!?
`syms x0 i j k a(i) b(i); xi = x0*symprod(a(i - j), j, [0 i-1]) + symsum(b(i-j)*symprod(a(i - k), k, [0 j]), j, [0 i-1]); x3
 = x0*symprod(a(3 - j), j, [0 3-1]) + symsum(b(3-j)*symprod(a(3 - k), k, [0 j]), j, [0 3-1])`